# ReactDOM sometimes work sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I wrote a very basic React code just to test if React is working. I've also included script tags that reference externally to react, reactdom and compiler. The strange thing is last week this sometimes work and sometimes doesn't. It would work 3 out of 20 refreshes. But now it won't work at all. Any idea what's causing it to work inconsistently?

```
<body>
  <div class="someclass"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(<h1>This is a test</h1>,document.getElementsByClassName('someclass')[0]);
</script>
```

Comment: is the script tag placed at the end of your html file? it could be that the document has not loaded and the script runs and can't find the element with class name 'someclass'

Comment: ^ ditto above. Check the order of the scripts and that you've placed this code just before the closing body tag. Otherwise you're going to need to provide further information.

Comment: I've actually rearranged the React script, the script that reference to 3 external files and the container div to every possible arrangement but still wont work.

Comment: `ReactDom.render` works... there is something you are not telling us. Post your entire code.

Comment: The entire code is too big to post here and no doubt ReactDom.render works because if I ran this locally it displays the text every time. What I'm trying to figure out is what makes this work inconsistently once combined with other codes within the page (the other code works perfectly by the way).

Comment: There is a chance that the 'other code' you were talking about was interfering React. I'm not sure how and why unless you post your code up here